# Calculate the following contour integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Using Stokes theorem 
I seem to find the integral value as $2\pi r^2$. Can anyone help me if I am right? 
How do i do it without using Stokes theorem?

$$C=\oint\limits_K \mathrm d \mathbf r\cdot \mathbf A$$

Where $\displaystyle \mathbf A=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf n\times\mathbf r,\quad
\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf n=1$, and $K$ is a circle with radius $R $ and $\mathbf n$ is the normal to the plane where the circle lives.

Comment: Is this HW or are you just curious for some reason?

Comment: @DJBunk : This question is something that i got from my friend. It looks interesting and he told me that it appears frequently in Electrodynamics in its general form . Can you help me?

Comment: @DJBunk : I did some calculation assuming that the circle is in $xy$ plane , now again i found it to be zero . using line integral and stokes theorem.

Comment: write out the components of the curl and then form a dot product, then see what happens

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical polar-coordinates ($\rho$, $\phi$, $z$) with $\mathbf{n}$ along the $z-$axis, we would get
$$\mathbf{A} = \frac{\rho}{2} \hat{\phi}$$
and along the circle $K$ of radius $\rho=R$,
$$d\mathbf{r} = R d\phi$$
Then
$$\oint_K d\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{A} = \frac{R^2}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi = \pi R^2$$

Now using [a vector identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_cross_product)
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{2} \nabla \times ( \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{r} ) = \frac{1}{2} \Big[ \hat{z} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{r}) - (\hat{z} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{r} \Big] = \hat{z}$$
So that
$$\int_{S} d\mathbf{S} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{A}  = \pi R^2$$
where the surface $S$ is a cylinder oriented along the $z-$axis with one (open) end on the circle $K$ and the other end closed at an arbitrary distance $z$ from the circle.

In the form presented, $A$ is the vector potential for a uniform magnetic field along the $z-$direction (and in this case of unit strength). I think this is called the radial gauge.